# ¿Como acceder correctamente a la base de datos de wordpress con PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, contact-form-7

tengo un pequeño problema con este script:

```
    $mensajes = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'post_type'     => 'flamingo_inbound',
        'post_author'=>1,
    ));
    print_r($mensajes);
```

Creo que todo el mundo conoce el plugin de flamingo, el caso es que necesito acceder a los datos guardados en la base de datos a través de este plugin (asi con php puedo decidir que mensajes pueden ver determinados usuarios) ahi la clave está en post_author en vez de poner el ID de la persona que envía el mensaje pongo el ID de la persona que lo tiene que recibir de esa forma puedo filtrarlo. El caso es que el script no funciona me devuelve todos los mensajes enviados (distintos post author) y no se que hacer.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: El [parámetro](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#parameters) para autores es `author` no es `post_author`, intenta de esto modo: **`'author'=>1,`**

Comment: hola, gracias por tu respuesta, no me funciona sin embargo si imprime si hago esto  'author'=>0,

Comment: Entonces verifica bien el ID del author antes de decir que es 1...

Comment: En la pregunta parece que querías filtrar por el autor cuyo id es  `1` si ese id es `0` o si es `9999` es indiferente. El hecho es que el parámetro para filtrar por author en `WP_Query` es `author`, no es `post_author`, como bien indica la documentación en el enlace que te puse en el primer comentario.